# Count number of char in a 2D grid C

Tags: c, arrays, char, ascii

I'm trying to count how many chars there in a 2D grid using 2 `for` loops. The code looks like this:

```
int number_of_boxes( int player, int height, int width, char**gameBoard ){
 int boxCount, i , a;
  for(i=0; i < (height*2) + 1 ; i++){
   for ( a = 0 ; a < (width * 2) + 1 ; a++){
      if(gameBoard[i][a] == (char)(player + 64)) boxCount++;
   }
  }
 return boxCount;
}
```

The `player` variable is an index for each player but in the grid they show ASCII characters.

1 = A, 2 = B and so on by adding 64 to the index and treating it like a `char`.  The `if` state intends to check over every character in the array of arrays for the ASCII character and add to a counter if it finds an instance of one.

For some reason, the `if` statement in this function is passing way too many times and the function is returning `122` or `120` when the only possible maximum is `4`. Is my `if` statement wrong?

Comment: boxCount is uninitialised. It contains garbage value.

Comment: Ahh, that fixed it, can't believed I missed that, thanks.

Comment: instead of using 65... use 'A'.  Makes the code way more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized boxCount.

```
 int boxCount, i , a;
```

Therefore boxCount currently stores some garbage value. I think thats why you assume that the if statement runs for many times.Try initializing boxCount.

```
  int boxCount=0, i , a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed out on initializing the `boxCount`:

Replace

```
int boxCount, i , a;
```

with

```
int boxCount=0, i , a;
```

Since the incrementing the uninitialized values is **undefined**.